# Scaling Zoom factors

Tags: c#, math

I am using the scroll wheel to zoom in and out on an object using the following method:

```
void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    lastMousePositionOnTarget = Mouse.GetPosition(grid);

    double max = 255;
    double min = .005;

    var deltaScale = Math.Max(Math.Log(scaleTransform.ScaleX), double.Epsilon);
    var delta = e.Delta > 0 ? Math.Max(e.Delta * deltaScale, .5) : Math.Min(e.Delta * deltaScale, -.5);
    double newScale = Math.Max(Math.Min((delta / 250d) + scaleTransform.ScaleX, max), min);

    scaleTransform.ScaleX = newScale;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY = newScale;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newScale);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I want to have it zoom more slowly when it is zoomed in closer to the max, and faster when the number is closer to the minimum. What I currently have sort of works but not very well.  How can I fix this to do what I want?

Comment: For ease of use/reading, precompute the scale/sizes, and let the mouse wheel adjust an index. @GEEF is on the right track as far as calculating the values.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand this right, you want your `deltaScale` to be large when zoomed in, but small when zoomed out. Thereby giving you fast zooming when close and slow zooming when far.

If `scaletransform.ScaleX` gets smaller as you're zoomed in, try something like this:

```
var deltaScale = Math.Max(K * 1/(scaleTransform.ScaleX), double.Epsilon);
```

where K is just some const you mess around with until it feels right.

If `scaletransform.ScaleX` gets larger as you're zoomed in, then try something like like your log, with a larger coefficient than 1:

```
var deltaScale = Math.Max(5*Math.Log(scaleTransform.ScaleX), double.Epsilon);
```

Comment: This is 1/2 way there - and one of the ideas I tried at the start. The K*1/Scale works, but it is too slow when zoomed in and too fast when zoomed out.

Comment: For example it with K == .5, Starting at a value of 20 it takes about 40 mouse scrolls to get to 19.  But once we hit 1.5 it just quickly to 1.1 -> .75 -> .08 -> .005.

Answer (score 2):

This is my final answer, I wouldn't have been able to come up with it if not for GEEF & Pawel so a big thanks to them for giving it their best shot.

```
void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    double max = 255;
    double min = .005;
    double scaler = 4;

    var deltaScale = Math.Min(Math.Max(scaler * scaleTransform.ScaleX / max, min),1) * Math.Sign(e.Delta);
    double newScale = Math.Max(Math.Min(deltaScale + scaleTransform.ScaleX, max), min);

    scaleTransform.ScaleX = newScale;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY = newScale;

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

I use a ratio of the current scale to the max to get the slope -- and don't allow it to go to fast (max 1) or too slow, min == the min scale.  Works OK.

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would not use value e.Delta for calculations (sign is of course needed). This value is not very reliable - in my experience it was close to random noise. Instead use constant value or some counter like how many times in a row zoom in was invoked and how many times in a row zoom out was invoked.

So my first try (with constant value) would look somehow like this.

```
void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    lastMousePositionOnTarget = Mouse.GetPosition(grid);

    double max = 255;
    double min = .005;

    var deltaScale = Math.Max(Math.Log(scaleTransform.ScaleX), double.Epsilon);
    var delta = e.Delta > 0 ? Math.Max(1 * deltaScale, .5) : Math.Min(1 * deltaScale, -.5);
    double newScale = Math.Max(Math.Min((delta / 250d) + scaleTransform.ScaleX, max), min);

    scaleTransform.ScaleX = newScale;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY = newScale;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newScale);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Version with counters would look something like this.

```
private double counter=0;
private bool isZoomIn=true;
void OnPreviewMouseWheel(object sender, MouseWheelEventArgs e)
{
    lastMousePositionOnTarget = Mouse.GetPosition(grid);

    if( (e.Delta > 0 && isZoomIn) ||  (e.Delta < 0 && !isZoomIn))
               IncreaseCounter(counter);//is another one in a row
    else
               counter=1;

    isZoomIn = e.Delta > 0;//we set this flag for next time

    double max = 255;
    double min = .005;

    var deltaScale = Math.Max(Math.Log(scaleTransform.ScaleX), double.Epsilon);
    var delta = e.Delta > 0 ? Math.Max(counter * deltaScale, .5) : Math.Min(counter * deltaScale, -.5);
    double newScale = Math.Max(Math.Min((delta / 250d) + scaleTransform.ScaleX, max), min);

    scaleTransform.ScaleX = newScale;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY = newScale;

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(newScale);

    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Note that I used pseudofunction IncreaceCounter instead of just incrementaion because you may want something else than just linear increase.

Comment: In my test cases e.Delta has always been a constant 120 or -120. But your answer makes me realize this may not always be the same on all computers. So I'll take this under advisement. As far as counters go I want to avoid those - I should be able to do some type of equation that knows how far I am zoomed in out based on the current Scale.X.

Comment: I was thinking the samething about the delta as well, using a const and the delta *direction* is the best option.